# How could I improve my below LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How could I improve my below LINQ query to have a better performance. What is the better way of writing this:

```
result = (from cd in dataContext.vRetailerWeeks
          where cd.MasterTrackingGroupID == masterTrackingGroupId
             && cd.RetailerWeek <= (from cd1 in dataContext.vCalendarDates
                                    where
                                        cd1.MasterTrackingGroupID == masterTrackingGroupId &&
                                        cd1.CalendarDate == retailerWeekDateTime
                                    select cd1.RetailerWeek).FirstOrDefault()
          orderby cd.RetailerWeek descending 
          select cd.RetailerWeek).Take(weekNo).ToList();
```

Comment: What is wrong with the performance now?

Comment: Do you need to pull back the list with the `ToList()` call? Is your bottleneck on the database side or the memory side?

Comment: If you just want generic feedback on your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a more suitable place.

Comment: I agree with @skaz. The ToList() is executing the code right that second where it might not have to. Additionally, you could put all that in a stored proc since you're only using one variable (as far as I could tell).

Comment: thanks. we have someone here who opposes using stored procedures and insists on using LINQ. to me, no difference as I can do both. at runtime, this query is compiled into only 1 database query but its LINQ looks not very nice and I thought maybe it can be refactored using JOIN, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the question is if you need to improve your linq query or your indexes in the database.

The best way it take the SQL that is begin generated (using SQL profiler, or log it from the datacontext).

If you are happy with the SQL generated, there is no need to futher change the linq query, it has done its job. So, try this SQL in Management Studio and examine the query plan. From there you can optimize your indexes.

If you are not happy, go ahead with the linq query.